# Wordpress Query Args - Only show post with meta_value greater than 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress loop with an array of arguments to show only specific posts (any posts with a deposit_amount value of 0).

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'cat' => '11',
    'meta_key'    => 'deposit_amount',
    'meta_value'  => 0
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

I would like to create a similar array but showing posts with a deposit_amount meta_value of greater than 0

i have tried to use the php greater than operator but breaks the code.

```
    'meta_value'  => >0
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'cat'               => '11',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'           => 'deposit_amount',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

just found 'meta_compare' => '>'

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'cat' => '11',
    'meta_key'    => 'deposit_amount',
    'meta_value'  => 0,
    'meta_compare' => '>'
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```